# Migrate similar stored procedures from various databases to single database

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 databases DB1, DB2 which have same table structure `tbl_Detail`. And both the databases have same stored procedure `sp_GetDetails` which has same scripts as below:

```
Create procedure sp_GetDetails
AS
Begin
    select * from tbl_Detail
End
```

I need to move this from both these databases and place in a single database DB3.

I tried using linked server and passed an input param as dbname to the stored procedure.

But it requires to convert the script into dynamic SQL.

Is there any other way to achieve this, as I do not want to use dynamic SQL, since there are hundreds such stored procedures and the number of statements in each stored procedure are more.

Comment: A linked server feels wrong for 3 databases all on the same instance. As for parametrising the database, yes, you need dynamic SQL. I suspect you have an [XY Problem](//XYproblem.info) here.

Comment: FYI the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)